# Jquery Picture Slider is not displaying any pictures

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a page where I use some sliders to display pictures, now I just went in to check how the page is doing and it shows no Images just a black box where the pictures should display:

[image: As you see the 2 out of 4 Sliders showing a black box]

Here you can see the issue, now I checked the code and I can't find the solution, I assume it has to do with some change on the Jquery Libraries as it was working before.

Here is the Code where I add the Jquery JS:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slides.js"></script>

         <script>
    $(function(){
  $(".slidejs-container").slidesjs({
    play: {
      active: true,
        // [boolean] Generate the play and stop buttons.
        // You cannot use your own buttons. Sorry.
      effect: "slide",
        // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
      interval: 5000,
        // [number] Time spent on each slide in milliseconds.
      auto: true,
        // [boolean] Start playing the slideshow on load.
      swap: true,
        // [boolean] show/hide stop and play buttons
      pauseOnHover: false,
        // [boolean] pause a playing slideshow on hover
      restartDelay: 2500
        // [number] restart delay on inactive slideshow
    }
  });
});
  </script>
```

Here is the code on the PHP for the Pictures to be displayed:

```
<section id="slideshow1">
<img class="thumb9" src="images/IMG-20140312-WA0002.jpg" alt="thumbail #1" />
                <div class="slidejs-container">
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/n.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/ff.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/kk.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/hh.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/gg.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/jj.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/ll.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/mm.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/nn.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/ww.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/xx.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/yy.jpg"/></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="images/zz.jpg"/></a></div>
                    </div>
```

Now I need the slider to be that size so Here is the CSS for it:

```
/*...Slideshow1...*/

#slideshow1 {
    width:40%;
    height:10%;
    float:right;
    background:#000;    
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#slideshow1 .thumb9{
    width:350px;
    height:190px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#slideshow1 .pagination{
    margin:26px 0px;
    width:100px;
    color:#fffff;
    display:none;
}

#slideshow1 .pagination li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 5px;
    list-style:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:none;
}

#slideshow1 img{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

#slideshow1 .slidesjs-pagination li a{
    display:none;
    width:12px;
    height:0px;
    padding-top:12px;
    background:none;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        color:#ffffff;
}

#slideshow1 slidesjs-navigation ul{
color:#ffffff;
display:none;
}

#slideshow1 slidesjs-play slidesjs-navigation slidesjs-playing{
color:#ffffff;
display:none;
}

#slideshow1 slidesjs-stop slidesjs-navigation{
color:#ffffff;
display:none;
}

#slideshow1 .slidesjs-navigation{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:none !important;
    float:right;
        color:#FFFFFF;
}

#slideshow1 ul.slidesjs-pagination{
color:#FFFFFF;
display:none;
}
```

Finally, I downloaded since the start the to JS files that added up top.

jquery.slides.js:

Which you can view from this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FwtS4y6SYBP32bZSxFF5SvI8u5arkBa/view?usp=sharing)

and jquery.slides.min.js:

Which you can view from this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FwtS4y6SYBP32bZSxFF5SvI8u5arkBa/view?usp=sharing)

Additional Information: I used the Chrome browser and it does seem as if it is moving the pictures, but I do see the information saying Overflow Hidden, but when I delete that from the Chrome Browser Developer Tools still doesn't display any pictures.

Any Ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind the was that I was adding a Div before each image on the the Slider:

```
<section id="slideshow1">
<div class="slidejs-container">
<img src="images/n.jpg"/>
<img src="images/ff.jpg"/>
<img src="images/kk.jpg"/>
<img src="images/hh.jpg"/>
<img src="images/gg.jpg"/>
<img src="images/jj.jpg"/>
<img src="images/ll.jpg"/>
<img src="images/mm.jpg"/>
<img src="images/nn.jpg"/>
<img src="images/ww.jpg"/>
<img src="images/xx.jpg"/>
<img src="images/yy.jpg"/>
<img src="images/zz.jpg"/>
</div>
```

And now it is working, thanks.